# Carving permuted sub-strings in a given string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, anagram

I need to recognize strings of the form xw(w^r)y in `O(n2)` time, where xw(w^r)y is a lower case string in the English alphabet.

Here, `w^r` is a permutation of the characters in w.

For example, the string `rtedafdfa` is of the desired form where x = rte, w=daf, w^r=dfa, and y is the empty string

What I have tried:

- Created a position map with key as the character and value as the list of indexes
- Created an index-list using the above position map for all characters that occurred >= 2 times.
- Sorted the index-list just created, in ascending order
- Discard all the indexes where consecutive difference is not 1
- From the final list of indexes carve out the w and w^r.

The above fails for some cases and I am not satisfied with all what I am doing. Here is the code in javascript:

```js
 let input = "raababaya";

 let posMap = {};

 for(let i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
  if(posMap[input[i]]) {
   posMap[input[i]].push(i); 
  }else {
   posMap[input[i]] = [i];
  } 
 } // O(N)

 let indexList = [];

 for(let char in posMap) {
  if(posMap[char].length >= 2) {
   // Has chances of permutation
   indexList.push(...posMap[char]);  
  }else {
   // No permutation 
  }
 } // Worst case O(N); Best Case O(N/2)


 indexList.sort((a,b) => a-b); // nlogn

 let finalPos = [];
 for(let i=0;i<indexList.length;) {
  if(indexList[i+1] && (indexList[i+1] - indexList[i] == 1)) {
   finalPos.push(indexList[i]);
   finalPos.push(indexList[i+1]);
   i += 2;
  }else i++;
 }

 if(finalPos.length >=4 ) {
  // Pattern detected
  let start = finalPos[0];
  let end = finalPos[finalPos.length - 1];
  console.log('Pattern detected');
  console.log('input: ' + input);
  console.log('Permutation detected: ' + input.substr(start,end));
 }
```

The above code works for input applied but will fail when the string is like:

```
aaaaaaaaababaya
```

What should be the better method for this? I am looking for two solutions to this. One in N^ 2 time and one with a better time complexity.

Comment: What is `x` in this case? Just a range of any lowercase characters?

Comment: And likewise for `y`?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Yes. In `raababaya` x will be `r`

Comment: @EvanKnowles Yes. In `raababaya`, y will be `ya`

Comment: What happens in case of multiple solutions possible? And for cases like raabababaaya, y can be ya or baaya

Comment: @marvel308 Multiple solutions could surely exist. We could cite one pair and exit. The need is to detect the strings of the form `X W W^r Y`

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in the following way

1. Instead of calculating the string is in the form of **xw(w^r)y**, instead we would search for **xwwy** since that is the base case
2. Since x and y can be empty we just have to find a non empty string w such that ww is a substring of the input str
3. Now using 2 loops i and j, check if the substring str(i, j) is of the form ww or not. This can be done in **O(26)** if you have a frequency array precomputed.
4. frequency[i][j] would denote the frequency of the j'th character in the substring str(0,i)
5. str(i,j) is of form **ww** if frequency of characters in str(i, mid) is equal to frequency of characters in str(mid+1, j).